# Loop over components inputs and remove a class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `validation` `method` which highlights my `input`s red but the issue I'm having is that when I click 'Reset', it recalls my page load `method` but I can't seem to figure out how to remove the `class` i previously added.

```
<template>
<form>
  <div class="form-group row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <label class="col-lg-1 col-form-label" for="nameField">Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input id="nameField" ref="nameField" type="search" class="form-control text-capitalize" placeholder="Enter your full name" :value="pdName" @input="pdNameInput" @blur="requiredCheck" />
      </div>
      <label class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-1 col-form-label" for="companyField">Company <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input id="companyField" class="form-control text-capitalize" type="search" :value="pdCompName" placeholder="Enter a company name" @blur="requiredCheck" />
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <label class="col-lg-1 col-form-label" for="telNumField">Contact no. <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input id="telNumField" class="form-control" type="search" :value="pdTelNo" @input="pdTelNoInput" @paste="telNoPaste" @blur="requiredCheck"
                  placeholder="Enter a contact number" v-telNoInput />
      </div>
      <label class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-1 col-form-label" for="extNumField">Ext no.</label>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input id="extNumField" class="form-control" type="search" :value="pdExtNo" @input="pdExtNoInput" @paste="extNoPaste" placeholder="Enter an extension number"
                  v-telNoInput>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
</template>



  <script>
    export default {
      pdInitPageStates() {
         let input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
         
// TRIED THIS
         for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
             console.log(input)
         }
    
         this.emailFormatErrorMsg = false;
         this.emailIncorrectFormat = false;
         
         this.pdName = this.$store.state.account.firstname + ' ' + this.$store.state.account.lastname
     this.pdCompName = this.$store.state.account.company;
     this.pdExtNo = this.$store.state.account.extension;
     this.pdEmailAdd = this.$store.state.user.adminemail;
     this.pdTelNo = this.$store.state.account.ddi;
     this.pdMobNo = this.$store.state.account.mobile;

     if (this.detailsChanged) {
         this.detailsChanged = false;
     }

     this.$refs.nameField.focus();
  },
                 
  requiredCheck(e) {
     let input = e.target;

     if (input.value === '' || (input.id === 'emailAddField' && this.emailFormatErrorMsg)) {
         input.classList.add('error');
     } else {
         input.classList.remove('error');
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]
I can't get a screenshot of when reset clicked as it removes the red as the value now populated

console.log

[image]

expand one

[image]

Only up to 5 is what im after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this :- https://itnext.io/5-ways-to-loop-over-dom-elements-from-queryselectorall-in-javascript-55bd66ca4128

From the Java Documentation :

The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

Perhaps what is unclear to many novices is the fact that iterating over a list using the for/foreach constructs implicitly creates an iterator which is necessarily inaccessible. This info can be found here